# Meson-Meson Scattering Data

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, large-hadron-collider, mesons, hadron-dynamics

Recently, I have been interested in the scattering amplitudes of mesons in the high-energy fixed-angle regime. I have come across a simple result, due to Brodsky et al., that predicts the scaling of such amplitudes with Mandelstam variable $s$.

However, I have been wondering whether there exists actual experimental data for differential cross-sections, such as $\pi + \pi \rightarrow \pi + \pi$ or $\rho + \rho \rightarrow \rho + \rho$ scattering, or other amplitudes including other low-lying mesons. I have been searching for such data on the HEPData website, but without any success.

Any comments on the existence of such data or suggestions on where to look for it would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Check experiments at the now renamed Los Alamos Meson Physics Facility (LAMPF) for meson scattering.

Regarding Brodsky and his constituent counting rules ($s$-scaling), see "Two Body Photodisintegration of the Deuteron" ($\gamma(d, p)n$) at SLAC and now TJNAF.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.

I don't know this literature terribly well. But as a rule, the efficiency of beam-beam interactions is terrifically small. Consider that the LHC is a storage ring for stable particles, which is filled and then runs for weeks at a time.

Any pion beam will be a "secondary" beam, produced by putting a "primary" beam of stable particles onto a fixed solid target. Another answer mentions LAMPF, a pulsed proton accelerator, which is now LANSCE, where the secondary beams are neutrons. LAMPF absolutely did not have counter-propagating pion beams which could scatter from each other, because that machine is a linear accelerator. Even for neutrons, where you can have slow neutrons from one accelerator pulse overtaken by faster neutrons from a later accelerator pulse, the intensities are too small for any neutron-neutron scattering. Pions are charged, which increases the cross-section, but neutrons live for minutes while pions live for microseconds.

At some point I convinced myself that a "beam" of rho mesons was basically impossible to make, but you should go through that exercise yourself rather than trusting my recollection. I have a vague idea that there is rho-nucleon data from Hall D at JLab.

Comment: The LHC beam is filled about once per day. The particles do not circulate for weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But for this answer it doesn't really matter. A day in the LHC takes a beam through each interaction region something like $10^9$ times. A factor of ten either way doesn't change the point here, which is that the beam-beam interaction is fantastically small.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the relevant data can be found in the paper listed below; however, reading the data is challenging.

G. Grayer et al., "High Statistics Study of the Reaction π⁻p → π⁻π⁺n: Apparatus, Method of Analysis, and General Features of Results at 17-GeV/c," Nucl. Phys. B, vol. 75, pp. 189-245, 1974. DOI: 10.1016/0550-3213(74)90545-8. Report Number: Print-74-0701 (CERN).